# Linear regression Weka to output predicted lap times

Tags: java, weka

I have a question regarding the machine learning done in Weka. In my case, I would like to predict sector times, which I recorded in the CSV file in my application. I have researched, and the best method to predict results seems to be the Linear regression, but I have been stuck on an issue regarding the proper model training. My data is as follows:

LAP_TIME,SECTOR,TIME,THROTTLE_POS_ENTER,THROTTLE_POS_EXIT,GPS_LAT_ENTER,GPS_LONG_ENTER,GPS_LAT_EXIT,GPS_LONG_EXIT,SPEED_ENTER,SPEED_EXIT
1,1,5,60.1,97.7,46.371044584160394,15.09848579764366,90,105
1,2,12,33.7,99.1,46.37047850291076,15.101122073829174,55,82
1,3,0,20.4,57.1,46.368578953235925,15.10340765118599,41,73
1,4,46,95.3,88.6,46.36551491974933,15.101220309734343,67,94
1,5,33,44.4,22.8,46.366923184209014,15.097428001463413,44,87
1,6,36,57.1,13.3,46.3678583054267,15.09299732744694,110,62
1,7,23,31.2,12.3,46.36953093408058,15.094324350357057,98,79
2,1,35,97.7,41.7,46.371044584160394,15.09848579764366,66,102
2,2,17,88.6,44.4,46.37047850291076,15.101122073829174,88,59
2,3,28,71.2,88.6,46.368578953235925,15.10340765118599,72,100
2,4,48,99.1,27.9,46.36551491974933,15.101220309734343,64,84
2,5,32,26.3,31.2,46.366923184209014,15.097428001463413,97,92
2,6,34,62.9,33.7,46.3678583054267,15.09299732744694,39,71
2,7,23,12.3,95.3,46.36953093408058,15.094324350357057,74,96

Regarding this gathered data, I'd like to predict the TIME attribute, which is measured in seconds. While using WEKA, I tried to use the Linear regression filter,and setting the TIME as class attribute, but the model predicted (when using the Cross validation split by 10 fold) shows too much error and the prediction is bad. What am I doing wrong?

```
=== Predictions on test data ===

inst#     actual  predicted      error
    1     36         26.083     −9.917 
    2     23         26.083      3.083 
    1     23         26.25       3.25  
    2     34         26.25      −7.75  
    1     46         23.167    −22.833 
    2     48         23.167    −24.833 
    1     12         30         18     
    2      0         30         30     
    1     28         26.462     −1.538 
    1     33         26.077     −6.923 
    1     17         27.308     10.308 
    1     35         25.923     −9.077 
    1      5         28.231     23.231 
    1     32         26.154     −5.846 

=== Cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===

Correlation coefficient                 −0.9199
Mean absolute error                     12.6136
Root mean squared error                 15.4765
Relative absolute error                100      %
Root relative squared error            100      %
Total Number of Instances               14
```

Edit: I am sorry if the code is not formatted right, I dont know how to paste the CSV file fully into codeblock.

Comment: Your data header has 10 columns, but the actual data only 8. Is there data missing? After removing the last two columns, I did a quick cross-validation run on the TIME attribute using a default LinearRegression and got a correlation coefficient of 0.6177.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I saw my mistake soon after I posted. The dataset has been translated and edited for the purpose of posting as I am not coding in English, and forgot to remove the columns. How can I mark this as the answer?